# Firefox Unresponsive script after wake-up/resume

Tags: firefox, hibernate, javascript, wakeup

Firefox is often unresponsive after waking up/resuming from hibernate/suspend on Ubuntu 12.04. After a while it will give me an error saying that some script is unresponsive and I get the choice to 'Stop' it or 'Continue' running it:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

I guess that Firefox doesn't like active scripts to be interrupted by hibernate/suspend, and thus freezes once I wake-up/resume my laptop. How do I resolve this, in order to make Firefox wake-up happy and snappy again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Type `about:config` in the URL bar and look for: `dom.max_script_run_time`, Double click it and change the time to 20.

Comment: I'll try it, but I'm not sure if giving the script more time will solve it.

Comment: I haven't had the problem any more since applying your suggestion, so I guess it works! I'll put the value back to 10 to see if the problem re-occurs. If so, then your fix is definitely working :)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is waking up and realizing that nothing has been happening for those running scripts for the past so many hours.  Additionally, if you're coming back from hibernation, the system is less responsive as it swaps all your programs back into RAM from swap space. It is rightfully notifying you that things have stopped.

I usually just tell it to 'continue' and it gives everything  the extra couple moments it needs to get moving again after a hibernate.

Comment: This answer doesn't help me. Your suggestion of just waiting for it to respond again is exactly what I want to stop happening and why I asked the question.